How to run balena etcher on ubuntu 20.04
I am trying to install linux mint using a usb stick. I am currently using ubuntu 20.04 and I dowloaded a .zip from https://etcher.balena.io/#download-etcher. After unzipping I see something like this:

But there is nothing there that I can run,no .sh file, nothing. Do you guys know how to run this?

did your research take you to this resource? Bear in mind after installing Linux Mint, Ask Ubuntu will no longer be able to offer support.

Hello Graham! your solution worked like a charm! Would you like to post it as an answer so I can accept it?

Thanks for letting me know. As requested I posted as an answer to your question. Accepting the answer will help others with the same or similar issue to find a solution.

The first step to installing Balena Etcher on Ubuntu is to first make sure that curl is installed on your system
sudo apt install curl

The next step is to download and run the installation script for Balena Etcher
curl -1sLf 'https://dl.cloudsmith.io/public/balena/etcher/setup.deb.sh' | sudo -E bash

The script will download and install everything you need and will add a new repository requiring you to only update APT and install the package with it after that.
sudo apt update

and install the corresponding package with:
sudo apt install balena-etcher-electron

Once done, Balena Etcher will be available in the main menu, and it will be ready to use.
The instructions on use are contained in this helpful reference

Check out its Github release page. You can download either the .deb package or the .AppImage format.
Install the deb package from terminal:
sudo dpkg -i balena-etcher_VERSION_amd64.deb

Alternatively, you can download the AppImage format. You can run it without installation but first, you need to make it executable:
chmod a+x balena-etcher_VERSION_x64.AppImage

